# wlan0 does not exist even with wireless driver and ndiswrapper installed

Tags: wireless, ndiswrapper

I have a Linksys AE1000 USB wireless adapter. I have installed the driver using Windows Wireless Driver and have run `ndiswrapper`. I get the wireless icon at the top right, but it detects no signal and there is no `wlan0` device defined.

I am running 12.04 LTS. How do I get this crazy thing to work? The chipset is Broadcom BCM4311.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the drivers have been unpacked into `/lib/firmware/` and then type

```
sudo modprobe b43
```

You might have to wait a couple seconds.